# How to pass object from parent(course) to child(update) in angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

How can I show data in the course information form?
explain:
when I click the edit icon in the course component, it does not show data in the update component,
I used @Input decorator but it still not working

[image]

**course.component.html**

```
<div>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let temp of courses">
              <td>{{temp.courseName}}</td>
              <td>{{temp.courseDuration}}</td>
              <td>
                  <button (click)="handleEditCourse(temp)" class="btn btn-success mx-1"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></button>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </div>
        <app-update [updateData]="selectedCourse" ></app-update>
```

**course.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild(UpdateComponent) updateComponent:UpdateComponent;

  courses: Course[] = [];
  selectedCourse:Course = new Course;

  handleEditCourse(temp:Course){
    this.selectedCourse = temp;
     this.updateComponent.showEditModal();
  }
```

**update.component.ts**

```
@Input() updateData:any;

  parentFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private childFormGroup: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm();
  }


  myForm(){
    this.parentFormGroup = this.childFormGroup.group({
      data:this.childFormGroup.group({
        courseName: ["", Validators.required],
        courseDuration: ["", Validators.required]
      })
    })

  }


  showEditModal(){
    $('#editModal').modal('show');

  }
```

**update.component.html**

```
<form #f="ngForm"  (ngSubmit)="formSubmit()" [formGroup]="parentFormGroup" >
                  <div formGroupName="data">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="courseName" class="col-form-label">Course Name:</label>
                    <input type="text"
                     class="form-control"
                     formControlName="courseName"
                     id="courseName"
                     name="courseName"

                    >
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </form>
```

Comment: You never use the `updateData` variable

Comment: i used it in the form
 myForm(){
    this.parentFormGroup = this.childFormGroup.group({
      data:this.childFormGroup.group({
       ** courseName: [this.updateData.courseName, Validators.required],**
        courseDuration: ["", Validators.required]
      })
    })
  }

but still not getting a data

Answer (score 0):

What Konrad says in his comment is 100% correct. you are passing the `updateData` in the component correctly, but you are never actually using the variable...

Something like this might prove useful:

```
myForm(){
    this.parentFormGroup = this.childFormGroup.group({
      data:this.childFormGroup.group({
        courseName: [this.updateData.name, Validators.required],
        courseDuration: [this.updateData.duration, Validators.required]
      })
    })

  }
```

Comment: i used it in the form
 myForm(){
    this.parentFormGroup = this.childFormGroup.group({
      data:this.childFormGroup.group({
        courseName: [this.updateData.courseName, Validators.required],
        courseDuration: ["", Validators.required],
        courseDescription: ["", Validators.required],
        instructor: [null, Validators.required]
      })
    })
  }

but still not getting a data

Comment: Two things, make sure the data us actually passed to your component (console.log will do), make sure the data structure is actually {name, duration}... I assume that in my response but you could very well have a different structure.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Page CourseComponent

```
<app-update [course]="selectedCourse"></app-update>
```

In the UpdateComponent TypeScript file, define the input property using the @Input() decorator:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Course } from './course';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update',
  templateUrl: './update.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update.component.css']
})
export class UpdateComponent {
  @Input() course: Course;
}
```

In the UpdateComponent template, use the course object to display or update its properties:

```
<div>
  <label>Course ID:</label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="course.id" name="id" />
</div>
<div>
  <label>Course Name:</label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="course.name" name="name" />
</div>
<div>
  <label>Course Description:</label>
  <textarea [(ngModel)]="course.description" name="description"></textarea>
</div>
```

HHere, the course object is used to display the current values of its properties in input fields, and the [(ngModel)] directive is used for two-way data binding.

Note that the Course type used in this example is just a sample, and you should define your own type or interface for the object being passed between the components.

Comment: I know by ngModel is working, but I am using a reactive form with validation. when I insert it in the reactive form then is not working `  myForm(){
    this.parentFormGroup = this.childFormGroup.group({
      data:this.childFormGroup.group({
     **   courseName: [this.updateData.courseName, Validators.required], **
        courseDuration: ["", Validators.required],
        courseDescription: ["", Validators.required],
        instructor: [null, Validators.required]
      })
    })
  }`